# android:sharedUserId in Manifest and AAR in NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I am developing two apps that have NFC capabilities. Android Application Record is great. Opening play store when the app is not installed is a great feature.

I want to write `AAR` to the NFC tags. Both of the applications have Acitivities that catches the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` Intent. But they also receive application installation changes and one of them disable the activity that catches the NFC `Intent` if the other app is already installed.

So there is always only one Activity to catch the intent that comes from the NFC tag. This is guaranteed. But if none of my both apps is installed, it does nothing because I am not using AAR right now.

I can only provide AAR of only one application. When I use AAR, android only sends the intent to that application. Even if my other application tries to catches the `IntentFilter`, phone opens Play Store.

Here is a possible solutions to that problem:

I can store unique urls in the tags and not store AAR. When I tap the phone to the tag, it asks what to do. Open a browser or open my activity? If my application is not installed I can redirect that webpage to the Play Store. This can work but the problem is: user can select browser even when my application is installed. This way, it will always open Play Store when that particular user taps his phone.

Finally, I have came across sharedUserId in Manifest. It would be great if Android OS would open the app based on sharedUserId in AAR or some sort of thing.

What do you guys think? Thank you.